# How can I git rebase from a shell script?

Tags: git, shell

If I'm automating the checkout of a branch, the pulling of that branches changes, and the fetching and rebasing of that branch onto another branch through a shell script, I can often encounter errors when rebasing, either due to schema updates or merge conflicts, etc.  How can I be dropped into an editor like vim during a rebase when the rebases are happening through a shell script that is checking out many branches in succession?

Comment: You want an automated script to operate in an interactive manner? Is someone going to be watching the script run to use the editor?

Comment: Yes.  Someone will be watching the script run.

Comment: What is happening at that point in the script now? Is git just bailing out on the rebase and killing the script? Is git bailing out on the next step since the rebase was not completed?